CMake: CUDA compiler found, yet "no GPU detected"
After upgrading cuda, cmake couldn't detect GPU for the following cuda project (it worked perfectly before upgrading):
# CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

if (NOT CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc")
    # required by CLion
endif ()

message("CUDA compiler: ${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER}")

project(cuda_hello_world CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(cuda_hello_world main.cu)

set_target_properties(
        cuda_hello_world PROPERTIES
        CUDA_ARCHITECTURES native
        CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
)


// main.cu
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

to reproduce:
$ mkdir build; cd build
$ cmake ..
CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 12.5.82
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc - skipped
-- Detecting CUDA compile features
-- Detecting CUDA compile features - done
-- Configuring done
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  CUDA_ARCHITECTURES is set to "native", but no GPU was detected.


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  CUDA_ARCHITECTURES is set to "native", but no GPU was detected.


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  CUDA_ARCHITECTURES is set to "native", but no GPU was detected.


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

The OS is Debian 12, and this CMakeLists.txt template has been working fine for quite a while until I rencently upgraded cuda.
The full list of my cuda package:
$ apt list --installed | grep cuda

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

cuda-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-cccl-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.39-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-command-line-tools-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-compiler-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-crt-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-cudart-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-cudart-dev-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-cuobjdump-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.39-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-cupti-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-cupti-dev-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-cuxxfilt-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-demo-suite-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-documentation-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-driver-dev-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-drivers-555/unknown,now 555.42.06-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-drivers/unknown,now 555.42.06-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-gdb-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-keyring/unknown,now 1.1-1 all [installed]
cuda-libraries-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-libraries-dev-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nsight-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nsight-compute-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nsight-systems-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvcc-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvdisasm-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.39-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvml-dev-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvprof-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvprune-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvrtc-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvrtc-dev-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvtx-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvvm-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-nvvp-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-opencl-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.39-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-opencl-dev-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.39-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-profiler-api-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.39-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-runtime-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-sanitizer-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.81-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-toolkit-12-5-config-common/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 all [installed,automatic]
cuda-toolkit-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-toolkit-12-config-common/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 all [installed,automatic]
cuda-toolkit-config-common/unknown,now 12.5.82-1 all [installed,automatic]
cuda-tools-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-visual-tools-12-5/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda/unknown,now 12.5.1-1 amd64 [installed]
libcuda1-i386/unknown,now 555.42.06-1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libcuda1/unknown,now 555.42.06-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libcuda1/unknown,now 555.42.06-1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libcudadebugger1/unknown,now 555.42.06-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-cuda-mps/unknown,now 555.42.06-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

more info:

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
cmake version: 3.25.1
nvidia-smi displays correct information
which nvcc prints /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc

Can someone help me fix this cuda issue so I can build cuda project again?

Try to manually compile and run some CUDA sample. I recently got an "unknown error" when trying to run any CUDA code after updating the driver for CUDA 12.5. After running a CUDA application once as root (after every reboot I guess), everything was normal again. See this conversation.

Turns out it was the same bug as runtime error 999.
In my case, neither restarting or reinstalling drivers works. It was solved with
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
sudo rmmod nvidia
sudo modprobe nvidia
sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm

